# How to find the altitude of a rocket?

Tags: rockets, altitude

I know this may be a very simple question, but is there any formula from which I can estimate the altitude of a liquid fuel (model) rocket based on the propellant, oxidizer, mass, density, etc?

I've searched for many formulas but none seem to be fitting.

Comment: You'd need a lot more inside that "etc."  Starting altitude, a fistful of numbers describing the weather, another fistful for the rocket's aerodynamic properties...

Comment: It is worth noting that liquid fuel model rockets do not really seem to exist -- while some amateurs have pulled off liquid fuel rockets, these are expensive and dangerous engineering projects inconsistent with the "model" regulatory category.

Comment: This is going to be very sensitive to the rocket performance.  Besides, this is the sort of question that if you ask the answer is no.  Anyone who can build such rockets safely can figure their performance.